# ProtonVPN не работает на Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сеть, безопасность, vpn

Всем привет, друзья! Подскажите пожалуйста, установил себе бесплатный GUI ProtonVPN на Ubuntu (22.04), а он не заводится...
Пытаюсь войти в учётку, прога задумывается, а потом выдаёт Network error.
Никаких антивирусов в системе нет, UFW спит, интернет-соединение в полном порядке.

Кто сталкивался -- помогите, пожалуйста...
Всем большое спасибо за помощь!

[image: скриншот ошибки]

Comment: а в винде работает? протон сейчас мало у кого работает

Comment: В винде полный порядок, работает как часики..)

Comment: в 18-й у меня он не работал по причине ошибки в сохранении паролей, одно время работала cli версия но потом и она перестала, последнее время работал через openvpn, там в описании протона написано, как это делать